# What is a checkbox whose value is -1?

Tags: vba

I have some Access queries which, among other things, sets the value of a form's checkbox to "-1". If 0 means "False" and 1 means "True", I suspect "-1" either means "Null" (which seems unlikely, since the TripleState property is "No"), or "Don't change the current value".

I experimented a little, but I can't tell what's going on without refreshing tables and queries that I shouldn't really be messing with. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: You're mistaken. Zero is false, -1 is true in Access. So a checkbox attached to a field with a value of -1 is checked.

Comment: Thanks. Make that an Answer and I'll give it a Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken. Zero is false, -1 is true in Access (actually, in VBA as well). So a checkbox attached to a field with a value of -1 is checked.

Comment: Interesting. In Excel formulas, at least, "True" evaluates to 1.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson: In Excel formulas, that's true. But not when it's stored internally or in Access. (I deal with this on a daily basis, importing Access data into SQL Server or exporting from SQL Server to Access. It's also an issue with importing dBase/FoxPro data.)

Answer (score 0):

`Null` is never anything other than `Null`. It has no numeric representation, it basically means "no value"; if -1 meant `Null`, that would make -1 some "magic value", and legit -1 values would be ambiguous. Nothing means `Null` other than `Null`.

When you declare a variable, you usually give it a type:

```
Dim someInteger As Integer
Dim someBoolean As Boolean
```

If you printed the values in each of these variables, you would get `0` for the `Integer`, and `False` for the `Boolean`.

You can then convert between types, and get the `Integer` value for any of these variables:

```
Debug.Print someInteger, TypeName(someInteger)
Debug.Print CInt(someBoolean), TypeName(someBoolean)
```

The integer representation of `someBoolean` will be `0`, because it's initialized to `False`.

The inverse works too - you can convert any `Integer` to a `Boolean`:

```
Debug.Print CBool(0)
Debug.Print CBool(-1)
Debug.Print CBool(42)
```

Only `CBool(0)` will print `False` - in VBA there is not really any specific `True`: there's "not false" though. `-1` is just a "not false" value that's convenient and that the language designers decided would make a good default numeric representation for the `True` Boolean value. But it's important to realize that *any non-zero value will also evaluate to `True`*.

This isn't a particularity of Access (or VBA) at all.